# Preg replace put searched letters in bold in result

Tags: php

I have a search box, and I want my results to be bold only on the letters from the beggining of the word (name or surname).

For example: "Mary Kidman".

Search: "Ma"

Expected result: "**Ma**ry Kidman"

Current result: "**Ma**ry Kid**ma**n"

My script:

```
function replace_accents($str) {
        $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        $str = preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde);/','$1',$str);
        return html_entity_decode($str);
    }

$q = $_POST['search'];

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    $id_docente = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    $searchable_name = replace_accents($name);

    if(stripos($searchable_name, $q) !== false) {
        $final_result = preg_replace("/($q)/i", '<strong>$1</strong>', $searchable_name);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the word-break marker `\b`, like so:

```
$final_result = preg_replace("/\b($q)/i", '<strong>$1</strong>', $searchable_name);
```

This way, it matches only at the start of a word, like **Ma**ry, but not Kidman.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uX2qS6/2):

```
Mary Kidman    ->  <strong>Ma</strong>ry Kidman
James Marconi  ->  James <strong>Ma</strong>rconi
Yo Yo Ma       ->  Yo Yo <strong>Ma</strong>
Ben Stillman   ->  Ben Stillman
Mark Manning   ->  <strong>Ma</strong>rk <strong>Ma</strong>nning
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capture groups:

For example:

```
/ma/gi
```

matches as **Ma**ry Kid**ma**n

Where as:

```
/(?:^| )(ma)/gi
```

matches as **Ma**ry Kidman

The first paranthesis is a non-capturing group that matches either the beginning of the string or a space. The second paranthesis is a capturing group that matches the string *ma*.

Answer (score -1):

preg_replace's parameter has a limiter just after the subject

```
$final_result = preg_replace("/($q)/i", '<strong>$1</strong>', $searchable_name, 1);
```

Comment: This still doesn't address OP's issue. What about, say, `Frank Kidman`?

Comment: In that case, no limiter is needed, just but \b after / and before ($q)/i.

Comment: Right. That's what OP wants - matches at the beginning of the word, not in the middle - but that's not what your answer suggests.